# Dates in all activity

Tags: java, android, android-datepicker

Hi am using Date picker in more than three class with same validation. Instead I must write in one class and call that function in other classes when I required, is it possible Below code for Date picker.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView tvDisplayDate;

    private Button btnChangeDate;

    private int myear;
    private int mmonth;
    private int mday;

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setCurrentDateOnView();
        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    // display current date
    public void setCurrentDateOnView() {

        tvDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);       

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        myear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // set current date into textview
        tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based, just add 1
                .append(mmonth + 1).append("-").append(mday).append("-")
                .append(myear).append(" "));
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        btnChangeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeDate);

        btnChangeDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            // set date picker as current date
            DatePickerDialog _date =   new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, myear,mmonth,
                    mday)
            {
                @Override
                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
                {   
                    if (year < myear)
                        view.updateDate(myear, mmonth, mday);

                    if (monthOfYear < mmonth && year == myear)
                        view.updateDate(myear, mmonth, mday);

                    if (dayOfMonth < mday && year == myear && monthOfYear == mmonth)
                        view.updateDate(myear, mmonth, mday);

                }
            };
            return _date;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            myear = selectedYear;
            mmonth = selectedMonth;
            mday = selectedDay;

            // set selected date into textview
            tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(mmonth + 1)
                    .append("-").append(mday).append("-").append(myear)
                    .append(" "));    

            Date dateObject1 = new Date(myear - 1900, mmonth, mday);

            Date dateObj2 = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

            if(dateObject1.before(dateObj2) || dateObject1.equals(dateObj2)){
                //the program runs normally
                }
                else{

                                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)

                                .setTitle("Wrong Data Input!")

                                .setMessage("The end Date must be Before the start Date, please insert new Date values")

                                .setNeutralButton("Ok",

                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,

                                int which) {

                                }

                                }).show();
                            }


        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `DateUtils` class with a static method, which takes in the dates, along with the context. This method can do the date validations and build the `AlertDialog` accordingly. You can call this static method this way.

```
DateUtils.dateValidator(Date, Context);
```

This can be called in the `onDateSet()` of your `OnDateSetListener` for each `DatePicker`.